# what is the difference between these three algorithm on the basis of time Complexity?

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

All these three algorithm is simply calculating the sum of the Array of size 10. here I'm bit confuse between the time complexity and also I wanted to which one is faster. Can you help me so that I can understand time complexity well.

**Algo 1**
In algorithm 1, the loop is running 10 times.

```
int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7, 8, 9, 10};
int sum = 0;
int size = 10;
int i = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    sum += arr[i];
}
cout<<sum;
```

**Algo 2**
In algorithm 2, the loop is running half times of the size of the array but in each iteration its doing double number of operation. Reducing the number iteration will make algorithm any faster?

```
int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7, 8, 9, 10};
int sum = 0;
int size = 10;
int i = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size/2; i++){
    sum += arr[i];
    sum += arr[size-1-i];
}
cout<<sum;
```

**Algo 3**

```
int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7, 8, 9, 10};
int sum = 0;
int size = 10;
int i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < size/2; i++){
    sum += arr[i];
}

for(int j = i; j < size; j++){
    sum += arr[j];
}
cout<<sum;
```

Comment: Note that time complexity doesn’t directly relate to real time. Even though they all have the same complexity they may have different real world performance. These two things should not be mixed. So asking “which one is faster” is quite hard, if not impossible to answer, and not related to big Oh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** They all have the same time complexity, O(n).

In terms of time complexity (big-oh notation), all of them are the same.

The first one performs `(one operation * size of array)` which is `O(n)` complexity (considering `n` is the size of the array).
The second one performs `(2 operations * (size of array) / 2)` which is `O(2 * n / 2)`, which is also `O(n)`.
The third one performs `(1 operation * size of array / 2 + 1 operation * size of array / 2)`, which is also `O(n)`.

The 3 algorithms might differ slightly in real time execution, but that's related to cache optimizations and related topics.

Comment: I wanted to know if I have to run my code faster then either I need to reduce the number of operation or the number of iteration. Is that right? also, Which one is slightly faster ? also

Comment: To make a code faster, you need to reduce the number of **operations**.

Comment: Taking cache optimizations into consideration, the **first** algorithm is slightly faster.
because there are no extra arithmetic addition (like in the second one), and the loop runs only once, so if there are some predictions the cpu has to make, it will hit a wrong prediction at least twice in the third algorithm because it quits the loop and goes into a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Here it seems that the approx time for all the three code is different because loop runs different number of times n and n/2.But when we go in its minute details then it is seen that number of statement executing is same..

In first

```
1 in loop;
loop runs n times;
total=n;
```

In second

```
2 in loop; 
loop runs n/2 times;
total n
```

In third

```
   1 in first loop;
   loop runs n/2 times;
   total for first is n/2;
   similarly in second ;
   total n
```

As seen number of execution is same therefore approx time is same

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned before, all algorithms have `O(n)` complexity. But execution time may vary.

There is a handy service [Quick C++ Bechmark](http://quick-bench.com/Pu2CKswrrz60NKZdIEgDEDcvnBM). I tested 4 algorithms using next code

```
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
constexpr int SIZE = 10000;
std::array<int, SIZE> arr;

static void algo1(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::iota(begin(arr), end(arr), 0);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum);
  }

}
BENCHMARK(algo1);
static void algo2(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::iota(begin(arr), end(arr), 0);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE/2; i++){
        sum += arr[i];
        sum += arr[SIZE-1-i];
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(algo2);
static void algo3(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::iota(begin(arr), end(arr), 0);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    int sum = 0, i;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE/2; i++){ sum += arr[i]; }
    for(int j = i; j < SIZE; j++){ sum += arr[j]; }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(algo3);
static void algo4(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::iota(begin(arr), end(arr), 0);
  int sum;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    sum = std::accumulate(begin(arr), end(arr), 0);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum);
  }  
}
BENCHMARK(algo4);
```

```
The results are:
algo1: 2770
algo2: 2913
algo3: 2782
algo4: 2770
```

Summary: algo2 is a bit slower, algo1, algo3, algo4 have same execution time.